# "Compacting" a SQL database after deleting records with SQLiteMan

Tags: skype, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLiteMan to edit/delete Skype message history, as described in numerous guides on the Net. I.e. I open Skype's `main.db` file in my profile folder using SQLiteMan and selectively delete some records in `messages` table. SQLiteMan allows me to do it either manually or by using SQL `DELETE` statement. On the surface it all works as expected: the records get deleted and Skype no longer displays the deleted messages in its history.

However, there's one little issue that does not seem to be covered in any Skype-history-management guides on the Net. The records are not physically deleted from `main.db`, but rather marked as "deleted" (which is certainly a reasonable thing to do from database management point of view). Opening `main.db` in binary editor shows that the contents of the deleted records is still perfectly visible in the file. Expectedly, the size of the `main.db` file does not change regardless of how many records I delete.

This, of course, is not acceptable from privacy/security point of view.

So, is there any way to force physical deletion of undesired records after the above "soft" deletion? Is there a way to "compact" the physical SQL database file? Alternatively, is there a way to ask the SQL engine to zero-out the contents of "soft"-deleted records to make them unreadable?

Comment: I'm not sure once the records have been deleted, but perhaps an `UPDATE` SQL statement that sets the relevant fields to `NULL` could do what you want.

Comment: @Excellll: Yes, just thought about that too. I can do `UPDATE` for the message text column (`body_xml`) before doing the actual deletion. It would still be interesting to know whether it is possible to physically delete the records. Or is it something that goes against physical principles of SQL database organisation?

Comment: @Excellll: BTW, setting fields to `NULL` also appears to be implemented by some sort of soft-labeling. It works at SQL level, but the physical database file still retains the original message text. So, for privacy purposes `NULL` dos not work. One has to use something like `xxxxxx....x`, i.e. a pattern that clobbers the whole field.

Comment: You might also be able to use the [`VACUUM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command, for SQLite.